# Are SRV records being stripped by DNS resolvers?

Tags: dns

I'm building a custom DNS Server that, among other things, serves `SRV` records and associated `A` and `AAAA` records. I can verify that querying the server directly returns the expected answer:

```
$ dig lseed.bitcoinstats.com SRV @139.59.143.87 +short
10 10 9735 2c932136c294204bc65c73266300b30fe8ccb99c24fb2261d2e9980a7e8ffe9.80.lseed.bitcoinstats.com.
10 10 6331 31ce6a2b947fdbc97f10405c4062848393cf8140f33cc492aa044fe47d18f59.c6.lseed.bitcoinstats.com.
10 10 8334 283a918ae4609473c01f2e19491e9202788150dbe8d4361a3a04f3a879e9f0a.45.lseed.bitcoinstats.com.
10 10 53258 2673073e3751681b0c55aa88e5af17522c6d6b32d7d210bf4d65439d063c1ba.91.lseed.bitcoinstats.com.
```

However when querying through my ISPs resolver (or any of the public resolvers, like Google's 8.8.8.8) I get an empty answer back:

```
$ dig lseed.bitcoinstats.com SRV @8.8.8.8       

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.10-Ubuntu <<>> lseed.bitcoinstats.com SRV @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 10994
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;lseed.bitcoinstats.com.                IN      SRV

;; Query time: 86 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 29 12:32:15 CET 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

The query returns immediately and I can see that my server receives an incoming query, however it is empty. Is it known behavior that the resolver strips `SRV` and additional answers? If this were the case, why is the query being forwarded at all to my server? Or is the error on my side, and the server simply replies with an incorrect answer?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the answers were stripped due to non-matching names in the answer. The query was asking for `lseed.bitcoinstats.com` while the answers were replying with another domain (`_lightning._tcp.lseed.bitcoinstats.com`) hence the resolvers were stripping the non-matching answers, leaving just an empty reply with no answers. Setting the domain in the answers equal to the domain in the question results in resolvers passing the answers through.